# Nginx hashtag rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How can I create this `rewrite` rule using regex in nginx:

http://www.example.com/my-path-here#hashvalue

to

http://www.example.com/my-path-here/#hashvalue ?

Answer (score 3):

Hash tags are a browser only concept and never sent to the server. So you can't rewrite then in nginx. Because when you visit `http://www.example.com/my-path-here#hashvalue` the nginx server will only be sent `http://www.example.com/my-path-here`

What you need is Javascript to handle such thing for you. Below is a sample html page which does that

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <script>
       var loc = window.location;
       if (!loc.pathname.endsWith("/"))
            loc.replace(loc.origin + loc.pathname + "/" + loc.hash);
    </script>
    </head>
 <body>
    <h1> You are here -  
    <script>
        document.write(loc.href);
    </script>
    </h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```