# Redirect for nginx with args

Tags: nginx, web, webserver

How to make redirect from this https://client.root.com/client/#/service-select?serviceRef=2121030305507970382 to this: https://client.root.com/client/#/service-details?serviceRef=2121030305507970382&locationRef=372133208406979272&date=2018-04-07 ? Exactly from one to another url. Web server - NGINX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx hashtag rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055093/nginx-hashtag-rewrite-rule)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx proxy\_pass : Is it possible to add a static parameter to the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532293/nginx-proxy-pass-is-it-possible-to-add-a-static-parameter-to-the-url)